# Writing a program to convert base 10 to base 2-16

Tags: c++, file-io, recursion

I am writing a program that reads from a file(called numbers.txt) puts those numbers into variables(number and base) and then runs them through the algorithm that will convert them to the base case of whatever variable base is(has to be 2-16 but could technically work for others) While doing that, the program must convert any numbers 10 or above into A,B,C and so on. However, I've run into a few hiccups that I can't seem to solve.

First off: how would I take a number in the middle of my algorithm and convert it to A,B,C...?

Second: I haven't had to write a program that reads from a file in a long time(like 1 and a half years) and am a bit rusty on it, and I keep getting the same integers. How would I get the program to move on to the next set of integers once I finish with the first set?

Third: one of the requirements is that the original number be between 0-1000000000 and if not it should output some statement saying it is invalid. In the code I've written I can't seem to get the logic in order. Any help there would be great :)

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    int convert(int number, int base)
    {

        if (number == 0 || base == 10)
        {
            return number;
        }
        return (number % base) + 10 * convert(number / base, base);


}
int switchToLetter(int number)
{
    switch (number)
    {
    case 10:
        cout << 'A';
            break;
    case 11:
        cout << 'B';
            break;
    case 12:
        cout << 'C';
            break;
    case 13:
        cout << 'D';
            break;
    case 14:
        cout << 'E';
            break;
    case 15:
        cout << 'F';
            break;
    }
}
int main()
{
    int number;
    int base;
    ifstream numbers("numbers.txt");
    numbers.open("numbers.txt");
    if (numbers.is_open())
         cout << "open";
    else
         cout << "not open";
    int inputvalue = number;
    if (inputvalue > 1000000000)
    {
        cout << "Decimal number too large for this program" << endl;
    }
    else
    {

        do
        {
            convert(number, base);
            cout << inputvalue << "in base" << base << "is" << number << endl;

        } while (inputvalue >= 0);
    }

    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: Are you asking "How can I print a number in base 16 in C++"?

Comment: no I'm asking how can I change a number in base 11-16 where if the number is 10-15 it changes to A-F(hope that makes sense)

Comment: You only read from the file once for each variable, so it makes sense they never change.

Comment: so I wouldn't be able to rewrite to that same variable if I used like a for loop or something of that nature?

Comment: What will your program do if it reads "10000000000000000"?

Comment: it should display "Decimal Number too large for this program"

Comment: I asked (rhetorically) what *will* it do.

Comment: Use @ to address a commenter when there is more than one.

Comment: @philipxy right now it isn't taking the right numbers from the file, so no matter what I put in the file it won't recognize the number. It is outputting -858993460 in base -858993460 is -858993460 right now.

Comment: You describe several problems, and perhaps if we ask more questions you'll add some more.  So far it sounds like you're not reading anything at all.  That could be because the file is not opened or the input is failing,  You don't check for either case.  I'd advise getting the program simply reading the numbers from the file in a loop and printing them out.  Once you have that working add the conversion.

Comment: Read about ifstream methods open & also operator void *() or operator bool().

Comment: @RetiredNinja alright I commented out everything below else cout <<  "not open" and ran it and it is giving me the not open line. Do I not have permission to open the numbers.txt file? Or am I doing the syntax wrong?

hmm I just ran it again and now it is outputting open...I'm not sure if I trust it to be honest

Comment: The syntax is sorta fine.  You don't need the open line at all if you pass the name to the constructor.  Either the file does not exist, you're not allowed to open it, or it does exist but not in the working directory of the program when you are running it.  If you are running it in an ide/debugger you probably need to put the file in the directory where your project file is or manually set the working directory in the ide.

Comment: @RetiredNinja okay I moved the file to the directory where the project file is and now it is saying open every time thanks :)

So for ifstream do I have to use the get command to get from the file and put it in a variable?

Comment: seems like you have left thanks for your help anyways :)

Comment: Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @philipxy I can tell you are trying to help, but you are just coming across as pretentious and it makes me not want to listen to anything you are saying.

Comment: My "10000000000000000" was Socratic: Read how `cin >> number` acts. Eg if the input represents an integer too large. My other comments are suggestions to do important things. Eg if you follow what it says you will enable yourself & others to find errors. PS: 1. Your current code never inputs from `ifstream numbers`. Neither does your `while`. 2. Surely `convert` should return a *string* in base `base`?